# Redirect URL with mod_rewrite with variable

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am looking to get a rule setup to change one of my URL's. After much research I understand the basics of `mod_rewrite`. The trouble I am having is the dynamic URL that is being re written. I have outlined in as much detail possible the task and desired outcome.

I currently have a url that looks like this:

```
http://www.myndness.com/my-canvas/{username}/
```

The `{Username}` is variable depending on which user you click on.

What I need to do is add `/?my_posts` to the end of that URL. This will then display the posts module by default for all users.

So all the users will follow the same URL pattern:

```
/User1/?my_posts
/User2/?my_posts
/User3/?my_posts
/User4/?my_posts
```

Apologies if I have missed anything.

I am using WordPress and have access to all files on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^my-canvas/[^/]+/?$ $0?my_posts [R=301,L,NC]
```